# Java "no such element exception"

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I am trying to do a lab where I am supposed to find the mode from a *numbers.txt* file. But I'm having problems storing the numbers in an array. I understand how to read the file but for some reason when I am trying to store the numbers I get a `java.util.NoSuchElementException`. I think that means the scanner I am using doesn't have anything else to read off of but I put the method in a try-catch already so I don't understand what's going on.

Here's the main part of the problem:

```
int [] modeArray = new int [total];
try {
    in = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
    for (int x = 0; x <= total; x++) {
        modeArray[x] = in.nextInt();
    }
}
catch (IOException i) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + i.getMessage());
}
```

And here's the rest of the code if you want to see the rest of the lab:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.IOException;
/**
 * lab 16.1
 * 
 * @author (Raymond Ma) 
 * @version (1/3/15)
 */
public class firstLab {
    public static void statistics() { 
        Scanner in;
        Scanner inTwo;
        Scanner inThree;
        int total = 0;
        double numbers = 0;
        double num = 0;
        double standardDeviation;

        //Average part
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
            while (in.hasNextInt()) {
                total += in.nextDouble(); 
                numbers++;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException i) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + i.getMessage());
        }  
        System.out.println("The Average of this huge list of integers is " + total/numbers);

        //Standard deviation part
        try {
            inTwo = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
            while (inTwo.hasNextInt()) {
                num = Math.pow((inTwo.nextDouble() - (total/numbers)),2);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException i) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + i.getMessage());
        }
        standardDeviation = Math.sqrt(num/(numbers-1));
        System.out.println("The Standard Deviation of this huge list of integers is " + standardDeviation);

        //This is the most annoying part (the mode)
        int [] modeArray = new int [total];
        try {
            inThree = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
            for (int x = 0; x <= total; x++) {
                modeArray[x] = inThree.nextInt();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException i) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + i.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("The Mode of this huge list of integers is ");// + )
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO it is better practice when reading to use `while (in.hasNext()) {...}` instead of a for loop, even if you know how many numbers you're reading. What line causes the problem?

Comment: It doesn't look like they are really answering the question down there. Even if you caught it, you would possibly be misrepresenting the data because of the error.

Comment: it highlights the  "modeArray[x] = in.nextInt();" line

Comment: I may have found it. modeArray[x] when x == total could be out of bounds. But wouldn't that throw an indexOutOfBoundsException? What is x when the error triggers?

Comment: @BenKnoble The problem has nothing to do with the array size. He gets that Exception, because he tries to read more data, than the file really has.

Comment: then `while (in.hasNext()) {...}` is probably a better solution isn't it @Tom?

Comment: He want to read int, so he should use `hasNextInt()` and also check the amount of read number to avoid an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NoSuchElementException` is a `RuntimeException`, not an `IOException`. Therefore it wouldn't be caught. Here are the hierarchies.

```
     java.lang.Object
            java.lang.Throwable
                   java.lang.Exception
                           java.lang.RuntimeException
                                    java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

VS.

```
     java.lang.Object
             java.lang.Throwable
                     java.lang.Exception
                              java.io.IOException
```

You can correct this by

1. **importing** the exception by `java.util.NoSuchElementException`  (right now you've only imported `IOException` )
2. **Catching** it. (For example: `catch(NoSuchElementException i)`  )

Also, in your `for` loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= total; x++) {
            modeArray[x] = inThree.nextInt();
        }
```

**Change x<= total to x< total because the array is indexed from 0 to total-1.**  (total is the array size)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the exception since the file doesn't contain enough integers, as you suspect.

Also, `NoSuchElementException` is not an `IOException`, so it will not be caught by the try-catch. Just add it to the catch statement:

```
int[] modeArray = new int[total];
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"))) {
    for (int x = 0; x <= total; x++) {
        modeArray[x] = in.nextInt();
    }
} catch (IOException | NoSuchElementException i) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + i.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: When I add the NoSuchElementException to the catch it says the class doesn't exist

Comment: @Zak That's because you only imported java.io.IOException. See my answer.

Comment: You need to add it to your imports, in the same way you imported `IOException`.

Comment: I tried to import it also but it still said that the class did not exist

Comment: The line should be `import java.util.NoSuchElementException;`.

Comment: It solved the part where it gets rid of the exception but it doesn't solve the problem of trying to input the numbers into an array

Comment: Either add more numbers to your input file or decrease the value of `total`.

Answer (score 1):

`NoSuchElementException` is not an `IOException`.  (See the object hierarchy tree in the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html).)  You have to `catch(NoSuchElementException i)`.

But there are two issues going on here:

1. In your code, `total` is the sum of the numbers, but you really want to use `numbers` when creating your array.  (E.g. for numbers 3, 5, 7, there are 3 numbers--that's what you want when creating your array size--but `total` would be 15.)
2. In your `for` loop, you want `i < total`, not `i <= total`.  Again, if you have three numbers, since the index count starts at 0, the maximum index in the array is not the size (3), but the size - 1 (2).